# pfSense IPv6 Configuration

Tags: networking, ipv6, pfsense

I'm running a virtual environment on a root server.
To connect all my maschines to the internet i got a pfSense setup up.

For the pfSense box it got let's say the  `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx::/64`-network.

Currently i set my `LAN` on pfSense to static and use the IP `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx::/64` and setup DHCPv6 for the `LAN` site form `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx:9000::1000/64` to `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx:9000::2000/64`.

On one of my virtual maschines I set it to static `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx:8000::2/64`. I allowed `ICMP` and ports `80` and `443` in the firewall to go to this maschine.

I can allways ping the `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx::` address of pfSense. The `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx:8000::2` of my virtual maschine is reachable like 20% of the time. Rebooting helps but not allways.

So what am I doing wrong? What should be made different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LAN and WAN need separate /64s. You seem to be using `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx::/64` on both sides, which will not work. You'll need for example `2a01:4f8:162:xxxx::/64` on the WAN and `2a01:4f8:162:yyyy::/64` on the LAN, with routing set up correctly so that the LAN addresses are routed through your firewall.

Comment: I know I expected that I need two but then it somehow worked with only one. I tries dividing my subnet into two `/65` networks but then i could not setup DHCPv6

Comment: It won't work with only one. Maybe you can ping your pfSense box (depending on whether it responds to ND on the other interface) but you won't be able to reach any machines on the LAN side without tricks like ND proxying. Using /65 will never work because your upstream will have it configured as one /64.

Comment: Your upstream should give you multiple /64s (usually a /56 or more) to run your own networks with. It might be that that's only part of a higher-level subscription though. If they don't provide enough /64s at all then they don't understand the concepts behind IPv6 and you'll be better off moving to a different provider.